# 60s/70s(?) comic where a guy in a coma is offered the chance to explore space and/or time

Tags: story-identification, comics

Read in sixties/seventies in one of those *Strange Tales* type of comic.

The main character is in a coma, maybe from a car accident or something.  He leaves his body and another character appears to him and takes him on a tour of space and maybe through time as well. "You can have all these wonders to behold", the guy says or words to that effect. "But you have to be willing to give up your earthly life and come with me."

Well, the guy decides that he'd rather stay alive where he can participate rather than merely observe. He wakes from his coma and somehow concludes that the guy was the devil.